# 100 seconds timeout when accessing Microsoft Graph with HttpClient - but not with curl - inside Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am running a .NET 6 / ASP.NET Core [application](https://github.com/KaiWalter/familyboard-aspnetcore/blob/stackoverflow/README.md) inside a **Docker** container on a **Raspberry Pi**.

[Dockerfile to see .NET setup](https://github.com/KaiWalter/familyboard-aspnetcore/blob/stackoverflow/Dockerfile)

This application is accessing Outlook and OneDrive using the **Microsoft Graph SDK**.

After really not touching the runtime environment it suddenly stopped working on Friday July 29th (so possibly a changed token behavior or alike on Azure Active Directory and/or Graph).

I removed the Graph layers of the application to break down the problem.

When I make a Graph call with `HttpClient` from this application / container

```
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");

            var response = await client.GetAsync("v1.0/me");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Ok(new HealthResult { Result = result });
```

I get a timeout after 100 seconds

```
2022-07-31T07:46:21.622984734Z fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
2022-07-31T07:46:21.623189265Z       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
2022-07-31T07:46:21.623227911Z       System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
2022-07-31T07:46:21.623305047Z        ---> System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
2022-07-31T07:46:21.623336974Z        ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

When I make the same call from inside this application / container with the very same access token over `curl` I get a response

```
            var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "curl";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-H \"Authorization: Bearer {token.AccessToken}\" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();

            string consoleResult = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            return Ok(new HealthResult { Result = consoleResult });
```

like

```
{"result":"{\"@odata.context\":\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity\",\"displayName\":\"John Doe\",\"surname\":\"Doe\",\"givenName\":\"John\",\"id\":\"1234567890abcdef\",\"userPrincipalName\":\"john.doe@outlook.com\",\"businessPhones\":[],\"jobTitle\":null,\"mail\":null,\"mobilePhone\":null,\"officeLocation\":null,\"preferredLanguage\":null}"}
```

What I already tried

- run the application from inside a **GitHub Codespaces** [devcontainer](https://github.com/KaiWalter/familyboard-aspnetcore/blob/stackoverflow/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json) : no problem
- [calling Graph without token over curl and HttpClient](https://github.com/KaiWalter/familyboard-aspnetcore/blob/stackoverflow/Application/Controllers/HealthContoller.cs) : same behavior, curl works, HttpClient does not work
- with TimeOut.InfiniteTimeSpan I get correct results after 7-8 minutes

What do I miss here? I will keep on dissecting the problem further and would be really thankful for any hints.

Comment: [This closed feature request from 5 years ago](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/issues/168) talks about a default timeout of 100 seconds, i think it's safe to say that docker is the cause, please investigate how that problem was solved.

Comment: A side question - You are passing the response using `var result = new
            {
                Response = response,
            };`. Should you not be reading thee response and send the serialized response - like `var result = new
            {
                ResponseEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectType>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()),
            };`

Comment: Another point, as per your posted error response, the requestUrl is `https://graph.microsoft.com/me`. Should it not be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`?

Comment: Right, I applied BaseAddress in the wrong way. It is supposed to only hold the host portion of a URL.

Comment: So with updated URL, are you getting the response or still it’s timing out?

Comment: @user1672994 thanks for your comments and hints so far. Now with TimeOut.InfiniteTimeSpan I get correct results after 7-8 minutes (?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClient` has a default timeout of 100 seconds. You can read about it at [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-6.0).

If you wanted to setup Infinite time then set it as shown below

```
httpClient.Timeout = TimeOut.InfiniteTimeSpan;
```

Comment: When building I get : error CS0117: 'TimeSpan' does not contain a definition for 'InfiniteTimeSpan'

Comment: Have you added the required namespace `System.Threading`? . Read about this property at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timeout.infinitetimespan?view=net-6.0)

Comment: user I had the namespace System.Threading already referenced. Following this article I changed to client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan; and then build & tests worked. Thanks