# Very long response time querying Microsoft Graph with .NET HttpClient from within Docker container on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

To further break down a problem I started investigating with [100 seconds timeout when accessing Microsoft Graph with HttpClient - but not with curl - inside Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73181623/100-seconds-timeout-when-accessing-microsoft-graph-with-httpclient-but-not-wit), I created a simple console application to reproduce the issue:

**ConsoleTest.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;

var client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");

var response = await client.GetAsync("v1.0");

Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
Console.WriteLine("========================");
Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
```

Executing it inside the container on a Raspberry Pi 3B with `date && ./ConsoleTest && date` it takes ~7 minutes until response is displayed:

```
Fri Aug  5 18:15:25 UTC 2022
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata","value":[{"name":"invitations","kind":"EntitySet","url":"invitations"},{"name":"users","kind":"EntitySet","url":"users"},{"name":"applicationTemplates","kind":"EntitySet","url":"applicationTemplates"},{"name":"authenticationMethodConfigurations","kind":"EntitySet","url":"authenticationMethodConfigurations"},{"name":"identityProviders","kind":"EntitySet","url":"identityProviders"},{"name":"applications","kind":"EntitySet","url":"applications"},{"name":"certificateBasedAuthConfiguration","kind":"EntitySet","url":"certificateBasedAuthConfiguration"},{"name":"contacts","kind":"EntitySet","url":"contacts"},{"name":"contracts","kind":"EntitySet","url":"contracts"},{"name":"devices","kind":"EntitySet","url":"devices"},{"name":"directoryObjects","kind":"EntitySet","url":"directoryObjects"},{"name":"directoryRoles","kind":"EntitySet","url":"directoryRoles"},{"name":"directoryRoleTemplates","kind":"EntitySet","url":"directoryRoleTemplates"},{"name":"domainDnsRecords","kind":"EntitySet","url":"domainDnsRecords"},{"name":"domains","kind":"EntitySet","url":"domains"},{"name":"groups","kind":"EntitySet","url":"groups"},{"name":"groupSettings","kind":"EntitySet","url":"groupSettings"},{"name":"groupSettingTemplates","kind":"EntitySet","url":"groupSettingTemplates"},{"name":"localizations","kind":"EntitySet","url":"localizations"},{"name":"oauth2PermissionGrants","kind":"EntitySet","url":"oauth2PermissionGrants"},{"name":"organization","kind":"EntitySet","url":"organization"},{"name":"permissionGrants","kind":"EntitySet","url":"permissionGrants"},{"name":"scopedRoleMemberships","kind":"EntitySet","url":"scopedRoleMemberships"},{"name":"servicePrincipals","kind":"EntitySet","url":"servicePrincipals"},{"name":"subscribedSkus","kind":"EntitySet","url":"subscribedSkus"},{"name":"places","kind":"EntitySet","url":"places"},{"name":"drives","kind":"EntitySet","url":"drives"},{"name":"shares","kind":"EntitySet","url":"shares"},{"name":"sites","kind":"EntitySet","url":"sites"},{"name":"schemaExtensions","kind":"EntitySet","url":"schemaExtensions"},{"name":"groupLifecyclePolicies","kind":"EntitySet","url":"groupLifecyclePolicies"},{"name":"agreementAcceptances","kind":"EntitySet","url":"agreementAcceptances"},{"name":"agreements","kind":"EntitySet","url":"agreements"},{"name":"dataPolicyOperations","kind":"EntitySet","url":"dataPolicyOperations"},{"name":"subscriptions","kind":"EntitySet","url":"subscriptions"},{"name":"connections","kind":"EntitySet","url":"connections"},{"name":"chats","kind":"EntitySet","url":"chats"},{"name":"teams","kind":"EntitySet","url":"teams"},{"name":"teamsTemplates","kind":"EntitySet","url":"teamsTemplates"},{"name":"auditLogs","kind":"Singleton","url":"auditLogs"},{"name":"authenticationMethodsPolicy","kind":"Singleton","url":"authenticationMethodsPolicy"},{"name":"solutions","kind":"Singleton","url":"solutions"},{"name":"privacy","kind":"Singleton","url":"privacy"},{"name":"compliance","kind":"Singleton","url":"compliance"},{"name":"security","kind":"Singleton","url":"security"},{"name":"identity","kind":"Singleton","url":"identity"},{"name":"branding","kind":"Singleton","url":"branding"},{"name":"directory","kind":"Singleton","url":"directory"},{"name":"me","kind":"Singleton","url":"me"},{"name":"policies","kind":"Singleton","url":"policies"},{"name":"education","kind":"Singleton","url":"education"},{"name":"roleManagement","kind":"Singleton","url":"roleManagement"},{"name":"drive","kind":"Singleton","url":"drive"},{"name":"communications","kind":"Singleton","url":"communications"},{"name":"identityGovernance","kind":"Singleton","url":"identityGovernance"},{"name":"identityProtection","kind":"Singleton","url":"identityProtection"},{"name":"deviceAppManagement","kind":"Singleton","url":"deviceAppManagement"},{"name":"deviceManagement","kind":"Singleton","url":"deviceManagement"},{"name":"reports","kind":"Singleton","url":"reports"},{"name":"admin","kind":"Singleton","url":"admin"},{"name":"search","kind":"Singleton","url":"search"},{"name":"planner","kind":"Singleton","url":"planner"},{"name":"print","kind":"Singleton","url":"print"},{"name":"external","kind":"Singleton","url":"external"},{"name":"appCatalogs","kind":"Singleton","url":"appCatalogs"},{"name":"teamwork","kind":"Singleton","url":"teamwork"},{"name":"informationProtection","kind":"Singleton","url":"informationProtection"}]}
========================
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  request-id: 221468c2-4c99-4ae6-b773-df4e5cc2da9a
  client-request-id: 221468c2-4c99-4ae6-b773-df4e5cc2da9a
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Germany West Central","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"FR3PEPF00000118"}}
  OData-Version: 4.0
  Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2022 18:22:03 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json
}
Fri Aug  5 18:22:04 UTC 2022
```

- executing from inside [a GitHub Codespace](https://github.com/KaiWalter/familyboard-aspnetcore/tree/stackoverflow) I get the response in <1 sec
- accessing another API - not Microsoft Graph - from within container shows a normal response time
- DNS resolution with `nslookup graph.microsoft.com` from within the container shows normal response times
- doing a `date && curl https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 && date` from within the container shows normal response times
- replacing Debian `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.7-bullseye-slim-arm32v7` with Ubuntu `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.7-jammy-arm32v7` had no effect - I was not yet able to get Alpine `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.302-alpine3.16-arm32v7` working

What do I miss here?

---

Additional measurements:

- `date && ./ConsoleTest https://ferien-api.de/api/v1/holidays/BW && date` : ~1 sec
- `date && ./ConsoleTest https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json && date` : ~1 sec
- `date && ./ConsoleTest https://catfact.ninja/fact && date` : ~2 mins (which is <1sec with curl)

What is the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Further breaking down this strange behavior to Docker image tag and .NET runtime identifier levels - [see problem with arm32v7 image running on Rasbian 32-bit on 64-bit Raspberry Pi 3B+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/138591/dotnet-returns-error-132-with-image-dotnet-sdk6-0-302-alpine3-16-arm32v7-on-ras) - I found out, that after a reinstallation of the 3B+ with **Rasbian 64-bit** and using **linux-arm64** .NET runtime, the application was behaving as intended again.